# Passing PAM parameters to UFW

Tags: shell-script, ssh, pam, ufw

On development server i want to open all ports for specific ip address after ssh login

But my ssh login script isn't working

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then                    
 ufw delete from $PAM_RHOST
else                                                          
 ufw allow from $PAM_RHOST
fi
```

In /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

Needing info why my script isn't working or/and how to debug it.

By default PAM-scripts is runned by root if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Have you tried inserting trace debugging into your script to log things (to a file in `/tmp`, say for example) to confirm things like if it runs, when it runs, what user it runs as, and what its environment variables are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. My problem was that $PAM_RHOST returns hostname not ip.

Corrected script

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=$(getent hosts "$PAM_RHOST" | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
  ufw delete allow from $ip
else
  ufw allow from $ip
fi
```

NOTE: Make sure ufw has IPv6 enabled because "getent hosts" can return either IPv6 or IPv4

Comment: +1. As a small improvement I do recommend using `getent hosts "$PAM_RHOST`` instead of the `dig` command as `getent` is the standard way to query the hostname database (including `/etc/hosts` which `dig` does not look at).

Comment: I wrote that first but something made me change it :)

Comment: Edited as Celada suggested.